# ssh on localhost without passphrase to allow svn+ssh://

Tags: svn, ssh, localhost, passphrase

A subversion repository uses property svn:externals to include files from another repository. Both repositories reside on the same server. Clients use svn+ssh:// to connect to the respositories without having to specify the passphase because gnome-keyring is used.

On the server we want to checkout files, including those specified with svn:externals. That means that on the localhost (=server) the repository is specified with svn+ssh:// (as part of the propset). When checking out files on the server the passphrase needs to be specified for each propset.

The question is: should I solve this problem by using ssh-keysign or can I use NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost in the ssh_config? Or I'm I reasoning wrongly?

Comment: ssh-keysign and NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost both relate to host authentication. They won't avoid having to specify a passphrase. Probably you want either a ssh-agent running on your server, or to use a passphraseless key for access from there.